# Averages of Consecutive Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the average of the sum of consecutive integers starting from one always an integer?

I am wondering about this because of a GMAT question: A set of consecutive positive integers beginning with 1 is written on a black board. A student comes along and erases one number. The average of the remaining numbers is 602/17. What was the number erased?

Comment: Given the set $\{1, 2\}$.  The average is $\frac{1+2}2 = \frac 32$ which is clearly not an integer.  So the answer to your initial question is "No".

Comment: If and only if the largest number is odd.

Comment: "average of the sum of consecutive integers", you perhaps meant "average of consecutive integers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, the average of the sum of integers from $1$ to $n$ is equal to
$$M_n = \frac{n+1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary an integer. In general the sum of consecutive integers is

\begin{equation}
\sum^n_{i=1} x_i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}

so general equation for average of any sum of consecutive integers from one to n is

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum^n_{i=1} x_i}{n} = \frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n} \text{ or } \frac{(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}

For example if the numerator is odd and denominator even then the average will not be an integer.

Using a specific example with n = 2 you have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{2(2+1)}{2}}{2}= 1.5
\end{equation}

which is not an integer.

Answer (score -2):

No.

Average(1,2) = 1.5

So there are cases when it is not an integer.

The answer to the second question is 7. The numbers 1-69 were written and 7 was erased.

Comment: No, the average of 1, 2 is 1.5.  If you had chosen $\{0, 1\},$ then the Average(0, 1) = 0.5.